# How do I get only the new/updated events from a calendar in Office365?

Tags: c#, outlook, calendar, office365, outlook-restapi

I'm a junior developer trying to figure out the Outlook365 REST API.

I'm using the office365 rest api to sync my events from my calendar.
On my first request, I get all the events from a time range. This returns a deltaToken. 
After that I add more events to my calendar and make another call using the last deltaToken returned from my calls. This request returns all the events (including the new ones) and 2 deltaTokens (the first is the one I've sent, and the second is a new one).
I only want to get the new events, not all of them. If I'm making the request using the deltaToken from my previous request, does that not mean that I've already synced all my previous events and shouldn't the next calls get only the new / modified events?

Below is a response. Is it ok to have 2 deltaTokens in my response?

> {"@odata.context":"https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/$metadata#Me/CalendarView,
>   "value":[list of events],
>   "@odata.deltaLink":"https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/Me/CalendarView/?startDateTime=2017-07-25T00%3a00%3a00Z&endDateTime=2017-09-01T00%3a00%3a00Z&deltatoken=GGXXX&%24deltatoken=GWXXX"
>   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not finalizing your first sync. The way sync works in the API is a little counter-intuitive. It isn't as simple as checking for a deltaToken to see if you're done.

The reason is that the first request with `Prefer: odata.track-changes` **always** returns a deltaToken, **even if** there are more results. The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#SyncCalendarView) give more detail here, but the general sequence is:

1. Do GET on the calendar view with `Prefer: odata.track-changes`.
2. Verify that `Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes` header is present in response. If so, get the `deltaLink` and do a GET on that.
3. Now enter your loop. If you get a `nextLink` in response, do a GET on that and repeat. If you get a `deltaLink`, the sync is done. Store the value until your next sync.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did the first GET with the Prefer: odata.track-changes header . I got the Preference-Applied. I did another GET with the deltaToken from the first step and my response is a deltaLink with 2 deltaTokens. The first is the one that I've sent, the second is a new one.
The problem is that if I add another event to my calendar and I make another GET with the last deltaToken I got, the response contains all my events, not all my changes. I just want the changes

Comment: Yeah you shouldn't have two delta tokens. Notice the first one is missing the `$` (%24) in front of it. Since it's missing that, the server doesn't recognize it as a parameter and starts a new sync. I would double-check your code that retrieves the deltaLink from the response and make sure you're not inadvertently dropping characters.

Comment: Oh, man.. that was it! I was missing the $. I checked and checked, but never though to check that. Thanks a lot!